# Controlling a program with "pywinauto" (Windows XP)

Tags: python, windows-xp, pywinauto

I'm almost new to Python and i started using the module "pywinauto" to control a program i'm using for my thesis.

I'm doing everything right like this:
    from pywinauto import application

```
prog=application.Application()
prog.start_('RAMPlus.exe')
prog.RAMPlus.MenuSelect('File->New')
```

Until here everything is fine but now the "New" window is something like this:

[image: screebshot of new window]

2 tables, 1 named "Upper Left" and the other "Lower Right".
 Each table has two lines "Lat:" and "Long:" and in each line you have 3 rows. I need to modify the value of each row

If i try

```
a.New.UpperLeftCombo.Click()
```

i get the message "pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.StaticWrapper object at 0x013A9BF0>" so i think the "pywinauto" acknowledges the "Upper left" and the "Lower right" but the rest i have no idea how to select.

Any ideas?

P.S: I saw somewhere that the creator of pywinauto, the user "markm" answers questions here.Can i tag him or something like that in this post so he can see it? I'm new to the site so don't know

Thank you very much in advance for the help

EDIT:do you know if i can copy the whole content of a window to a txt file with pywinauto?

Comment: (1) Instead of posting an image, would it be possible to post a link to the image?  (2) You can't tag specific users.  You've tagged your question 'pywinauto'; if markm logs in and checks the pywinauto tag, he should be able to see your question easily.  At the time of writing this was been the first pywinauto question for about a week and a half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm managing to get around it with Swapy, so this question is solved.

One more question guys, with is it that "pywinauto" and "swapy" don't work on 64-bit systems? I have two workspaces, one 32-bit and one 64-bit and i really would like to work in both of them

Comment: I successfully use Python 32bit + pywinauto on x64 systems. I've seen only one problem (related on 64bit) - some trouble with automation icons in system tray.

Comment: really?i can't install pywinauto or sendkeys in my 64-bit through easy_install. Can you tell me how to install it then?

Comment: (1) Install Python 2.x (32bit), (2) download pywinauto archive http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywinauto/files/latest/download, (3) unpack & run "...python.exe setup.py install"

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to 'select' a row in the tables directly.  There won't be a method in pywinauto such as `a.New.UpperLeftCombo.SelectRow()`.

What you might be able to do instead is to send keypresses to the tables to choose a row and then select it.  For example, you might be able to use the up and down arrow keys to choose a row and then press Space to select it.  Use the [TypeKeys](http://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/code/pywinauto.controls.HwndWrapper.html#pywinauto.controls.HwndWrapper.HwndWrapper.TypeKeys) method of `HwndWrapper` to send keypresses to a control.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the answer. The image is here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/854/52979714.jpg/

Answer (score 0):

pywinauto can work with tables if it is Windows ListView common control. ListViewWrapper has enough methods for a table:  `ColumnCount(), GetSelectedCount(), Select(item)`, etc.

I am not sure you have been using a table control by `a.New.UpperLeftCombo.Click()`, it seems like `UpperLeftCombo` is just some text(`pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.StaticWrapper object at 0x013A9BF0>`).

Try to get all controls of the window and look for a `ListView` control.

You may do it with `a.New.print_control_identifiers()` or the easiest way is to use one of the GUI tools for pywinauto. By pure chance I am the author of one of them.

Comment: I downloaded the Swapy program and i'm delighted with it. Nice work SWAPYAutomation ;)